# How to write two functions, one on top of the other

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How can I write this

[image]

in LaTex?

Comment: In case you are interested, `tikz-cd` offers an out-of-the-box solution easier than those in the linked post: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[r,"f"] & B\ar[r,shift left,"g_{1}"]\ar[r,shift right,"g_{2}",swap] & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}`

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, since I think it's not really a duplicate of the linked one. The situation here is slightly different; on the linked question the situation is not about commutative diagrams.

Comment: True, but the other solution provided a way (albeit, a rather complicated one) of writing what I needed. Either way, I prefer your solution (much easier to remember!), so if you write it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: Answers cannot be provided as long as the question is closed. That's why I voted to reopen :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package you have the possibility to use shifts (for example, `shift right`, `shift left` with a possible value for fine tuning position) to easily typeset this kind of sets of multiple arrows in commutative diagrams.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
X\ar[r,"f"] & Y\ar[r,shift left,"g_{1}"]\ar[r,shift right,"g_{2}",swap] & Z
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
X\ar[r,"f"] & Y\ar[r,shift left=1ex,"g_{1}"]\ar[r,shift right=0.4ex,"g_{2}",swap] & Z
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A `pstricks` solution, with the `psmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15 , linewidth=0.6pt, labelsep=1.5pt, nodesep=3pt, colsep=1.2cm, shortput=nab}
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\begin{psmatrix}
X & Y & Z
%%%
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}^{f}\ncline[offset=2pt]{1,2}{1,3}^{g_1}\ncline[offset =-2pt]{1,2}{1,3}_{g_2}
\end{psmatrix} \]

 \end{document}
```

[image]